# Merge an animated gif over a static png at a specific location using ImageMagick

Tags: animation, canvas, imagemagick, animated-gif

I have managed to paste an animated gif over a static png and obtained an animated gif from
those sources with the following command.

```
convert canvas.png animation.gif test.gif
```

and it works, but the animation and the canvas share the upper left corner, which is not what I want.
By reading a little I discovered that I have to use either the `-composite` option or the command, but I have not found examples of the right syntax to use.
I tried this:

```
 convert canvas.png   animation.gif -geometry +780+275  -composite test01.gif
```

which gives a static image with just the first frame of animation.gif
I tried other syntax but just produces errors.

What is the right way to accommodate the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in Imagemagick. It takes a special null: operator to separate the two images and -layer composite. Also you must use -page or -set page rather than -geometry when using -layers composite. The following is Unix syntax. For Windows, remove the \ before the parentheses.

```
convert canvas.png null:  \( animation.gif -coalese -set page +780+275 \) -layers composite -layers optimize test01.gif
```